# Kafka stream for processing event which takes long time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Spring Boot Kafka Stream application that reads the records do some HTTP calls and transform the record into another form. This transform record is then sent to the producer.

```
final KStream<String, String> toSquare = builder.stream(eventTopic,
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
toSquare.mapValues(recodProcessor::processMessage).to(notificationTopic,
                Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
```

Sometimes `processMessage` method is taking more than 5 min to execute based on the input event. `max.poll.interval.ms` is configured as 5 min. This is triggering rebalancing. Also, we are seeing the lag start building up for the particular partition.

How Kafka stream can be configured to handle such a scenario like throwing an error and pushing a record in DLQ and moving to the next record?

Answer (score 0):

For now, Kafka Streams doesn't support handling errors and pushing a record to a DLQ, so you'll need to implement it yourself.

Also, note that making external calls from Kafka Streams is not considered a best practice for the reason you describe here.

But if you need to do this in Kafka Streams, maybe try using a [KStream.process](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Named-java.lang.String...-) method and make the HTTP external call from there and keep track of the time if the response doesn't come back in time, forward the record with a flag of some sort indicating the failure, and you could use either `branch` downstream to route the failed records to a DLQ or simply use a [TopicNameExtractor](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/TopicNameExtractor.html)